# FluentSecurity: RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler does not get called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, fluent-security

I have a ASP.NET MVC page with FluentSecurity. I have it set up using Ninject according to [this article](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/setting-up-fluentsecurity-to-use-ninject-for-dependency-resolution). I have a `DenyAnonymousAccessPolicyViolationHandler` that works well. I added a `RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler`.

In my setup, I have

```
configuration.For<SettingsController>().RequireRole(CMSRoles.Admin);
```

If I navigate to the `SettingsController` with a user without the required role, the `RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler` does not get called. Instead I am redirected to the LogOn page as defined in `web.config`.

Am I missing something? According to the FluentSecurity documentation it should work.

**EDIT**: I have a custom RoleProvider registered and I use it with FluentSecurity:

```
configuration.GetAuthenticationStatusFrom(() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
configuration.GetRolesFrom(() => Roles.GetRolesForUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name));
```

**EDIT**: I created a minimal sample app: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73642/MvcApplication1.zip. If you go to /Logged that you are redirected to the login page so the `DenyAnonymousAccessPolicyViolationHandler` works. You can login with any username and password you want. The go to `Settings` and you see that you are redirected to the login page instead of `RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler` beeing executed.

Comment: Can you post some code to show how you're setting this up so we can try to help you.

Comment: @lopezbertoni my setup is exactly the same as the linked article

Comment: Please post then your DenyAnonymousAccessPolicyViolationHandler code. That's probably just redirecting to the Login page. Also, post how you're configuring Fluent Security, how you're getting roles, etc. It's hard to help without looking at code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I have it set up, hope this helps:

In App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs I bind the policy handlers:

```
kernel.Bind<IPolicyViolationHandler>().To<DenyAnonymousAccessPolicyViolationHandler>();
kernel.Bind<IPolicyViolationHandler>().To<RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler>();
```

I also configure Fluent Security like this (using Ninject Service Locator):

```
var locator = new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);

SecurityConfigurator.Configure(
            configuration =>
            {
                configuration.GetAuthenticationStatusFrom(() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                configuration.GetRolesFrom(SecurityHelpers.UserRoles);

                //HomeController and other configurations
                configuration.For<HomeController>().Ignore();

                configuration.ResolveServicesUsing(ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances);
             }
             );
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleSecurityAttribute(), 0);
```

Then for each policy, I have an implementation of IPolicyViolationHandler

```
public class RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler : IPolicyViolationHandler
{
    public ActionResult Handle(PolicyViolationException exception)
    {
        //Make sure you're redirecting to the desired page here. You should put a stop here to debug it and see if it's being hit. 
        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

I have a working solution using Custom Membership/Role Providers and Fluent Security. I posted what I think is the core configuration. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Added how to get roles.

```
public static class SecurityHelpers
{
    public static IEnumerable<object> UserRoles()
    {
        var currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        var roles = Roles.Providers["MemberAccountRoleProvider"]; //Custom Role Provider Name
        return currentUser != null ? roles.GetRolesForUser(currentUser).Cast<object>().ToArray() : null;

    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**:
I looked at your code and it's working fine. Add this to your code so that you can redirect to where you want. Right now you're just returning an Http results:

```
public class RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler : IPolicyViolationHandler
{
    public ActionResult Handle(PolicyViolationException exception)
    {
        //return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(exception.Message);
        return
            new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Test", controller = "Account"})); //Created a view for testing
    }
}
```

When I try to get the settings page I'm hitting the RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler.
[image: Settings Page]
[image: Debugger]

Comment: I think the only difference is how we get roles for the user. Can this be the problem? The Ninject stuff is equivalent

Comment: @IgorKulman I updated to show how I actually get the roles. It's hard for me to tell if that's the problem but you're welcome to try it.

Comment: try putting a stop at var roles = Roles.Providers["MemberAccountRoleProvider"]; to see if it's being executed. If it's not being called at all then there might be a configuration problem.

Comment: it does get executed when trying to access the forbidden controller, by FluentSecurity according the calls stack

Comment: @IgorKulman Updated the answer, the code you provided is working fine.